# Polar plot: Modify digit precision in Y-axis label

Tags: vb.net, charts, label, axis, polar-coordinates

I can't seem to be able to modify the digit precision of the Y-axis label values in a polar plot.  I am pretty sure the long labels shown in the image below are the Y-axis, but just in case, neither of the following two lines has any effect on digit precision.  Is there another form of syntax required for changing these axis labels in polar plots?

```
 chart1.ChartAreas(k - 1).AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "N2"
 chart1.ChartAreas(k - 1).AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "N2"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
chart1.ChartAreas(k - 1).AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "0.00";
```